# Python Plotly Radar Chart with Style

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, radar-chart

I'm trying to the image shown below and I thought python would be a good idea to do this but I'm not sure. I want to randomize lots of football players' stats, make a radar chart for each and save the charts as images. [image]

But the plotly radar charts are not so stylish and I really want to make something stylish. How to turn the below demo code into the reference image and is it possible?

Here's a demo code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

categories = ['Defending','Speed','Attacking',
              'Technical', 'Team play']

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=[1, 5, 2, 2, 3],
      theta=categories,
      fill='toself',
      name='Alice'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=[4, 3, 2.5, 1, 2],
      theta=categories,
      fill='toself',
      name='Bob'
))

fig.update_layout(
  polar=dict(
    radialaxis=dict(
      visible=True,
      range=[0, 5]
    )),
  showlegend=False
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [polar layout](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/polar/), it seems that Plotly does not offer much options when it comes the grid shape itself. However, Plotly allows you to create [your own templates/themes](https://plotly.com/python/templates/#creating-themes) or [examine built-in themes](https://plotly.com/python/templates/#examining-builtin-themes).

As a starting point, you should probably analyze the `plotly_dark` theme as it has some features similar to your picture.

#### simple example with built-in template

[image]

###### dataset.csv

```
categories,player,points
Defending,alice,1
Speed,alice,5
Attacking,alice,2
Technical,alice,2
Team play,alice,3
Defending,bob,4
Speed,bob,3
Attacking,bob,2.5
Technical,bob,1
Team play,bob,2
```

###### code

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
fig = px.line_polar(df, r="points",
                    theta="categories",
                    color="player",
                    line_close=True,
                    color_discrete_sequence=["#00eb93", "#4ed2ff"],
                    template="plotly_dark")

fig.update_polars(angularaxis_showgrid=False,
                  radialaxis_gridwidth=0,
                  gridshape='linear',
                  bgcolor="#494b5a",
                  radialaxis_showticklabels=False
                  )

fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor="#2c2f36")
fig.show()
```

With the above code I don't think it is possible to modify the color of each nested shape. To be able to do so, you will probably have to create your own template and color each nested shape separately.

#### creating grid shape

You might have to try something similar the code below to create your desired grid shape.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

bgcolors = ["#353841", "#3f414d", "#494b5a", "#494b5a", "#58596a"]
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatterpolar(
    r=[42]*8,
    theta=[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315],
    marker_line_width=2,
    opacity=0.8,
    marker=dict(color=bgcolors[0])
))

for i in range(1, 5):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
        r=[44-6*i]*8,
        theta=[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315],
        marker_line_width=2,
        marker=dict(color=bgcolors[i])
    ))

fig.update_polars(angularaxis_dtick='')
fig.update_traces(fill='toself')
fig.update_polars(angularaxis_showgrid=False,
                  radialaxis_showgrid=False,
                  radialaxis_gridwidth=0,
                  gridshape='linear',
                  radialaxis_showticklabels=False,
                  angularaxis_layer='above traces'

                  )
fig.show()
```

[image]

The colors are off but the general shape is good.